# Get Value of absolute date range in kibana

Tags: kibana

I want to use the selected Timerange in kibana as a "filter value".

So for example if the time range is set to:

```
From: 2019-10-16 14:00:00.000
To: 2019-10-16 14:15:00.000
```

I want to use the "To-Value-Timestamp" like the "now" value so i can get all records which are older than one day for example, like "To-Value-Timestamp"-1d.

Is this even possible and if yes, how?
I am looking forward to your answers!